# R: Data frame manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, heatmap

I have a data frame as follows:

```
Name    W1xH1    W2xH2  W3xH3  W1xH2
A           0       10     20     10
B          10      100    200     20
C           0        0     10     40
```

But I want to get the data frame as follows:

```
     H1    H2    H3
W1   10    70     0
W2    0   110     0
W3    0     0   230
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? The reason I want this is I want to create a heatmap on W* and H*. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example output appears to be incorrect. Please verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", use `stack` and `xtabs`.

```
temp <- stack(mydf[-1])
temp1 <- data.frame(temp, 
                    do.call(rbind, 
                            strsplit(as.character(temp$ind), "x")))
xtabs(values ~ X1 + X2, temp1)
#     X2
# X1    H1  H2  H3
#   W1  10  70   0
#   W2   0 110   0
#   W3   0   0 230
```

Here, "mydf" is defined as:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), W1xH1 = c(0L, 10L, 0L), 
  W2xH2 = c(10L, 100L, 0L), W3xH3 = c(20L, 200L, 10L), W1xH2 = c(10L, 20L, 40L)),
  .Names = c("Name", "W1xH1", "W2xH2", "W3xH3", "W1xH2"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```